# C compilation errors: undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, makefile, raspberry-pi

On the PI, I needed the i2c.so library using this git: https://github.com/silentbobbert/pi_sensors. When running makefile from this git to get the i2c.so, i received this error:

[image]
[image]

Here are the .c and the .h files:
https://github.com/silentbobbert/pi_sensors/tree/master/Info/LinuxInterface

For reference, here is the contents of makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC    = gcc
FLAGS        = -c -Wall -Werror -fpic
DEBUGFLAGS   = -O0 -D _DEBUG
RELEASEFLAGS = -O2 -D NDEBUG

TARGET  = i2c.so
SOURCES = $(shell echo *.c)
HEADERS = $(shell echo *.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

PREFIX = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin

all:
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(RELEASEFLAGS) $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) -shared -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: By "C#", did you actually mean "C"?

Comment: @Oli well, in URLs, `C#` is just `C` with an empty `id` ;)

Comment: no the sln is in c# which requires this library

Comment: Here are the .c and the .h files:
https://github.com/silentbobbert/pi_sensors/tree/master/Info/LinuxInterface

Comment: @Hamoudy: This code is C, you're using GCC.  The question has nothing to do with C#, AFAICS..

Comment: ok, thanks I'll remove the reference to c#

Comment: Even though the compiler thinks it found all the headers it needs, there is a major problem with missing information.  You should ideally find out where `ioctl()` is declared (the first message).  The rest of the messages might be from not including the `ioctl()` header, but are more likely somehow related to the `i2c*` functions and names not being found in the header where they're expected.  Maybe you need to track down which headers are included: add `-H` to the GCC command line options.

Answer (score 1):

as others have said, this is C code not C#.

Anyhow, you have two errors (and they do not relate directly) to the makefile but rather your compilation environment and the code itself.

OK, so how to approach something like this.  First notice the first line in your screen-capture, that is the command that is being executed that is generating the error messages,  I'll reproduce it here for you;

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic -O2-D NDEBUG i2c_get.c i2c_set.c i2cbusses.c i2cset.c util.c
```

With this command we are compiling (note the -c flag) a bunch of source files into a single object file, the presence of the `c' flag implies that no linking is performed here.  This is relevant so we know where along the tool-chain we are, and the type of errors we can expect (typically either syntax errors or missing header files).

The first error;

```
i2cset.c: In function 'check_funcs'
i2cset.c:56:2 error: implicit declaration of function 'iotcl' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

is kinda saying, "hey, I can see that `ioctl` is a function, but you haven't told me anything about it so I'm going to assume that its signature is `int ioctl()` — a function with an indeterminate (but fixed, not variadic) argument list that returns an `int`".  Given that you are compiling on a Linux-based system, adding `#include <sys/ioctl.h>` to the top of the file should fix this error.

The second error;

```
i2cset.c:63:7: error: 'I2C_SMBUS_BYTE' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

is related to the first error; and it is kinda saying 'hey, you haven't told me anything about I2C_SMBUS_BYTE'.  Again, the most common reason for seeing this error is a missing header file.  Looking at the source files you've provided a link to, it seems that `I2C_SMBUS_BYTE` is defined in 
the header file `i2c-dev.h`, which however appears to be included in `i2cset.c` by: `#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>`.

At this point I'd insure that your compiler (gcc) can find the header file.  From the error messages you are getting, I'm guessing that it is not, but you should be seeing an error message from the compiler about not being able to find the file.  Also, if the file is on your system check to see if has the appropriate contents as compared to the git site.

Finally, the remain errors that you are seeing *should* be fixed as well as they are all basically the same thing.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, but the ioctl.h is aready in the i2c_set.h file: http://i.imgur.com/obkVIMg.png

Comment: also the i2cset.c file does not have #include <linux/i2c-dev.h>, instead it has the #include "i2c-dev.h"

Comment: However, when i visited the sys/ directory, I did not find a ioctl.h: http://prntscr.com/3xqi6x

Comment: @Hamoudy, looking at the file on git I see the following include files [lines 23-31]:#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include "i2cbusses.h"
#include "util.h"
#include "../version.h"

Comment: @Hamoudy, with gcc there is a set of predefined directories that the compiler will search for include files.  In the case of #include <sys/ioctl.h>, notice that there is no leading slash, so this is interpreted as a sub-directory of one of the system include paths.  Try looking in /usr/include/sys for the file, or better yet try doing this as the root user: `find / -name ioctl.h` and see if the header file is anywhere on your system.